# How can I properly URL Encode an array in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, urlencode

I have found that `encodeURIComponent` works in most cases but when I pass an array, it doesn't work as expected. Here is my code:

```
var orderArray = [223746903996283,223525203804543]
var orders = encodeURIComponent(orderArray);
Logger.log(orders);
```

`orders` value is `223746903996283%2C223525203804543`.

The expected value is `%5B223746903996283%2C223525203804543%5D`.

Thank you so much in advance.

[image: Sample output on an online encoder]

Comment: You are trying to encode the string not the array.

Answer (score 6):

Convert it to a string first using `JSON.stringify`:

```js
var orderArray = [223746903996283,223525203804543]
var orders = encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(orderArray));
console.log(orders);
```